# Tutorial for Azure Speech to Text

Tags: azure, speech-to-text

I'd like to convert audio file to text data by using Azure Speech to Text. Anyone knows good tutorial for that? I could find a tutorial below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-python

But the sample's audio source is from microphone not audio file.

Thanks.

Comment: You could have a look this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/) and  currently audio to text not available.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to ask any more help.

Comment: i have found this to be useful with python 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py#L123

Answer (score 0):

There is an offical audio sample named [`whatstheweatherlike.wav`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/whatstheweatherlike.wav) which you can get from [`samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/whatstheweatherlike.wav`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/whatstheweatherlike.wav) of the GitHub Repo `Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk`.

And here is my sample code I wrote and partial refered to the offical tutorial [`Quickstart: Recognize speech with the Speech SDK for Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-python). I installed the current version `1.6.0` of Azure Cognitive Services SDK for Speech via `pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech`.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

speech_key, service_region = "<your api key>", "<your region>"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename='whatstheweatherlike.wav')
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()
print(result.text)
```

The text recognized from the audio sample file is as below.

```
What's the weather like?
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For me it only recognizes the first sentence and not the complete wav file . Do I need to pass any additional params?